# When I use the xdg-open command on a particular file it gives me > on the next line

Tags: command-line, xdg-open

I am opening a program with the command `xdg-open file`.

I use this command a lot so I don't think this is a typing error.

When I try to open this file it just gives me `>` on the next line and no matter what I type nothing happens. I use this command to open other applications in the same directory, but only this specific one(it's an audio file) has the error.

I even redid the file but the same error occurred. I have made more audio files after this error but the same thing occurs. When I use the GUI to open it then it works just fine. I am using Audacity to make this file.

Response to comments: this filename has a `'` in it, but why does that matter?

Comment: Is there something different about the file names when the error occurs?  Are there special characters or spaces in the file names?

Comment: Why have you **not** provided the full command including the filename?

Comment: I figured it out the filename had an ' in it but why does that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the filename contains a `'` character. This has special meaning to the shell - it is an opening quote, and the shell is waiting for the closing quote, another `'`

To use the `xdg-open` command or any other on this file, you may use double quotes around the filename, or escape the `'` character using `\`

```
xdg-open "unicorn'rainbow"
xdg-open unicorn\'rainbow
```

will both work as normal.